# Show tab or menu choice as the active element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is not a jQuery question.  I'm not using an `<anchor>` or `list` for my menu.  I want the menu (tab) item to be a different color when that menu (tab) is active.  I've tried using CSS `:active` and `:selection`, but they don't work.  I'm using a `<label>` inside a `<p>` tag for my menu:

```
<div id="MainMenu">
   <p class="floatLeftP" id="SiteName">Site Name Here</p>
   <p class="floatLeftP"><label id="ViewLink1" onclick="mainMenuChg('Home')">HOME</label></p>
   <p class="floatLeftP"><label id="ViewLink2" onclick="mainMenuChg('Offered')">OFFERED</label></p>
   <p class="floatLeftP"><label id="ViewLink3" onclick="mainMenuChg('Input')">INPUT</label></p>
   <p class="floatLeftP"><label id="ViewLink4" onclick="mainMenuChg('Wanted')">WANTED</label></p>
   <p class="floatLeftP"><label id="ViewLink5" onclick="mainMenuChg('MyAccount')">My Account</label></p>
   <p class="floatLeftP"><label id="ViewLink6" onclick="openHTTPS()">Sign Up!</label></p>
   <p class="floatRightP"><label id="ViewLink7" onclick="openHTTPS()">Sign In</label></p>    
</div>
```

The CSS `:active` is for a link, but I'm not using a link.

When most of the menu items are clicked a function named `mainMenuChg('argHere')` runs.

```
function mainMenuChg(argPage) {
    window.location.href = "#" + argPage;
};
```

This changes the URL in the browser, which then causes an angularJs router to trigger.

I don't want to use angularJs for this.  I only want to use JavaScript.  I can get a menu item to change color using:

```
document.getElementById(theID).style.color = "yellow";
```

But then it stays that color.  If I click another menu item, then two menu items have turned yellow.  I need to set the current `<label>` to a different color, then turn the last one back to it's original color.  The menu items are different colors, so I need a way to set it back to the default.

I need a way to store the old `id` in a variable that doesn't loose it's value.  But if I define a variable inside the function, it seems to loose it value.

I've seen a couple of questions that show a solution in jQuery, but not JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone's kind answers, I've been able to come up with a working solution. There is a full working version at jsFiddle, the link is at the bottom of the page.  Here is the HTML.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="myMenu" id="xyz1" href="#" title="Update"><span>Home</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="myMenu" id="abc2" href="#" title="Save"><span>Save</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a class="myMenu" id="hij9" href="#" title="User"><span>User</span></a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the code:

```
var menuHome = document.getElementById('xyz1');
var menuSave = document.getElementById('abc2');
var menuUser = document.getElementById('hij9');

menuHome.addEventListener('mouseup', clickedHome, false);
menuSave.addEventListener('mouseup', clickedSave, false);
menuUser.addEventListener('mouseup', clickedUser, false);

var currentMenuItem = '';

function clickedHome() {
    if (menuHome === currentMenuItem) {
        return;
    };
    //alert("home menu clicked: ");
    menuHome.style.background = 'blue';
    //alert('currentMenuItem: ' + currentMenuItem);
    if (currentMenuItem !== undefined && currentMenuItem !== "") {
        //alert("it ran: ");
        currentMenuItem.style.background = '';
    }
    setCurrent(menuHome);
}

function clickedSave() {
    if (menuSave === currentMenuItem) {
        return;
    };
    //alert("home menu clicked: ");
    menuSave.style.background = 'cyan';
    if (currentMenuItem !== undefined && currentMenuItem !== "") {
        //alert("it ran: ");
        currentMenuItem.style.background = '';
    }
    setCurrent(menuSave);
}

function clickedUser() {
    //alert("home menu clicked: ");
    if (menuUser === currentMenuItem) {
        return;
    };
    menuUser.style.background = 'blue';
    if (currentMenuItem !== undefined && currentMenuItem !== "") {
        //alert("it ran: ");
        currentMenuItem.style.background = '';
    }
    setCurrent(menuUser);
}

function setCurrent(argMenu) {
    //alert("set current ran: ");
    currentMenuItem = argMenu;
    //alert('currentMenuItem: ' + currentMenuItem);
};
```

Here is a working example at jsFiddle.

[Highlight Active Menu Item on Menu Bar](http://jsfiddle.net/VzcrU/2/)

Answer (score 1):

First you can give a `class` to all labels.

For example, `class="this-is-a-tab"`.

Then you can edit a little the function and add another parameter.

`function mainMenuChg(argPage,tabId)`.

And on the labels...

`onclick="mainMenuChg('Home',this.id)">`

Now back to the function...

```
function mainMenuChg(argPage,tabId) {
    //First We Remove the Yellow from all Tabs
    var tabs = document.getElementsByClassName("this-is-a-tab");
    //Then go through them
    for(var i=0; i< tabs.length; i++)
    {
         tabs[i].style.color = "blue";
    }
    //Then we give yellow to the tab we clicked on.
    document.getElementById(tabId).style.color = "yellow";
    window.location.href = "#" + argPage;
};
```

Comment: Removing the color from all the tab or menu elements would assure that nothing inadvertently gets left with the old color.  So that's good.  However, you are setting all the tabs to blue.  Some of my menu items are red, and some are blue.  So the items that are red by default would now be blue.  I didn't know about being able to get a whole class of elements and looping through them.  So that is very helpful.

Comment: What I meant with blue is actually the default color that your tabs currently have, so you can set that whatever you like, you can also set the color for specific tabs, for example, `tabs[0].style.color = "purple";` will make the first tab purple.

Answer (score 1):

Check if following pseudo code helps you

```
prevObj; // global variable.

if(prevObj != undefined) {
  precObj.style.color = original_color;
}
this.style.color = "yellow";
prevObj = this;
```

Comment: Yes, this helps.  I need to set a global variable outside of the function so it maintains it's value.  The problem with this code, is that the `original_color` is not known.  There are multiple different colors.  I could hard code the original colors, or set up a `key:value` object to look up what the original color was, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.